# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '?'

Tags: python, svm

I have tried to run a SVM program, and I got the above error. The code is here below. Please point out the error in it.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
data = pd.read_csv('risk_factors_cervical_cancer.csv')
X = np.array(data[[#some data elements]])
y = np.array(data[#some data elements])
print(X)
print(y)
print(X.shape)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, 
random_state=30)
classifier = svm.SVC()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)    #the error occurs here 
y_pred = svm.predict(X_test)
acc = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

`

Comment: You probably tried to put `"?"` as an element of X or Y.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: your `classifier` can't convert `X_train` or `y_train` to float, that is error, try converting them manually to float using `float(X_train)` and `float(y_train)`.

Comment: There are some strings or other non-numerical characters (like `'?'`) in your data. You will have to convert them to numbers so that the ML models can work on them. Depending on the type of data there are various schemes available to encode string features to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As @Guimoute wrote, preprocessing your data is always necessary in order to train it with any machine learning algorithm. Try `X.head(10)` to get an introduction to the data you are using. Your error occurs because there is a value "?" in your X column. Replace it with some reasonable number, i.e. the mean of the column for example in order to get better results.